# blender 2.60: "Draw Edge Length" in "Mesh Tools 1" option

Tags: blender

Anyone know where to find the "Draw Edge Length" option that used to be available in edit mode in the Editing Panel as the "Mesh Tools 1" option in older versions of Blender? I would like to see the edge lengths of all sides of the selected objects when I edit them so that I can resize them accurately with extrude and so forth.

Comment: I found the answer. The edge length can be set by pressing N in the 3D view to bring up the properties panel and then checking the "Edge Length" option under "Numerics". Sorry for the question, I had the properties panel hidden and could not see this option.

Comment: You must also be in Edit mode to set this option otherwise it will not show up in the aforementioned Properties window.